# Want to use Duckling in Rasa_Nlu. What are prerequisite to use Duckling in it

Tags: rasa-nlu

I am using Duckling Pipeline in config.yml file of rasa_nlu. and i have started 8080 port server also but when i am running rasa_nlu.evaluate i am getting an error  2019-08-25 16:27:00 ERROR    rasa_nlu.extractors.duckling_http_extractor  - Failed to connect to duckling http server. Make sure the duckling server is running and the proper host and port are set in the configuration. More information on how to run the server can be found on github: https://github.com/facebook/duckling#quickstart

```
Error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /parse (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001E393E68978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context'))
```

I have started Duckling Server in localhost and port 8080 and it is running.
http://0.0.0.0:8000/  .But error says

```
Failed to connect Duckling server
```

Config.yml file

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "DucklingHTTPExtractor"
  # url of the running duckling server
  url: "http://0.0.0.0:8000"
  # dimensions to extract
  dimensions: ["time"]
- name : "nlp_spacy"
```

Expected result is :- When user enter 'Tomorrow' . I should get Tomorrow Date . Eg.- If Today Date is 25-08-2019 . SO Output should be 26-08-2019

Answer (score 0):

Try using localhost instead of "0.0.0.0"

```
- name: "DucklingHTTPExtractor"
  url: "http://localhost:8000"
  dimensions:
  - time
```